# Get device rotation in Y axis

Tags: libgdx, axis, accelerometer

So using LibGDX accelerometer methods, I'm able to get the rotation of the device in the X and Z axes in degrees with this code:

```
 @Override
public void render(float delta) { 
    float accX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX(),
            accY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY(),
            accZ = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();

    float moduleValue = (float) Math.sqrt(accX * accX + accY * accY + accZ * accZ);

    //Here I do the gravity compensation
    accX /= moduleValue;
    accY /= moduleValue;
    accZ /= moduleValue;

    float xRotation = (float) Math.atan2(accY, accZ) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees,
            zRotation = (float) Math.atan2(accY, accX) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;}
```

However, get the rotation in the Y axis is not that easy to obtain, and if I try to get it by this way, it returns erroneus values.

Comment: Hmm, what values for Y-rotation do you get and what values do you expect? As it is, this code does not produce any values at all.

Comment: @Trilarion I use this code in the render method.

Comment: [See also this previous question on finding yaw from a 9DOF sensor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/problem-finding-correct-value-for-yaw). Note that accelerometers on their own are not able to detect rotation about the axis of gravity, so you need to apply [tag:sensor-fusion] with a second sensor like a gyroscope to get this information. Note also that the code above labeled "gravity compensation" doesn't actually compensate for gravity, it just normalizes the acceleration vector, which could still contain a mix of gravity and motion signals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your gravity compensations are doing, but you may not be taking units into account. The docs for `Input.getAccelerometerY()` say

> The rate of rotation around the y axis. (rad/s)

To convert this to degrees, you have to convert from rad/s to rad then to degrees

```
float accY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
float degrees = accY * deltaTime * MathUtils.RadiansToDegrees;
```

Then `degrees` is how much the phone rotated on the Y axis this frame. Note that both the X and the Z axes also return in (rad/s).

**Update:**

Thanks to DMGregory for his comment to get to the root of this issue. The docs are indeed mixed up. The `getGyroscope` functions are the ones that give rotation in `rad/s`. The `getAccelerometer` functions give acceleration in `m/s^2`

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java) for the Android implementation of the Input interface all it does it sets up a `SensorEventListener` and then copy the values of each `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` event into an `accelerometerValues[3]` array and returns one of its members on a call to `getAccelerometer`. The same occurs for `Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE` and the `getGyroscope` functions.

For reference on what these android specific values mean, one can look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

**TLDR;**

The docs are wrong. For rotation, use `getGyroscope`. It is the function that will give you rotation around the phone's local axis in `rad/s`

Comment: That quote from the docs looks a bit fishy. Usually an accelerometer would be measuring acceleration in Gs. Radians per second of rotation would normally come from the rate gyroscope instead. [I notice that the docs here are blank for the getGyroscope methods](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getGyroscopeX--) which might suggest there was an error in creating the document, where the gyroscope entries accidentally got placed in the accelerometer section.

Comment: Good catch. The docs are wrong. I updated my answer