# How would I process accelerometer data to use it for camera rotation?

Tags: javascript, three.js, accelerometer

I'm using Three.js to make a web-based 3D first-person game.  I would like the player to be able to control the camera rotation with their device's accelerometer.

The sensor data is received via the `DeviceMotionEvent` event listener. Here is an example of what it returns:

[image: DeviceMotionEvent output.]

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: This question is too light on details. Please edit it to explain more - what kind of sensor are you using (IMU, MARG, etc), and which stage of the process do you need help with? Reading input from the sensor? Performing [sensor fusion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/problem-finding-correct-value-for-yaw/114518#114518) or smoothing? Transforming that motion data into a rotation representation? Scripting your camera to follow this rotation? Or something else? It's a bit much to ask for a ready-made "complete solution" - show us what you have so far & where you're stuck.

Comment: @DMGregory edited it. do you need more details?

Comment: @DMGregory probably I need to set camera's yaw and pitch. basically, the same thing you would set with a mouse in most FPS games, but with accelerometer.

Comment: So, would it be fair to describe your problem as "how do I convert from an acceleration vector to a camera angle?" In that case, you should explain what kinds of device motion should translate into what kinds of camera motion (as with many geometric problems, images probably help here). In particular, I note that your rotation rate data is null. Without this, you won't be able to determine whether the device is rotating around the axis of gravity, so your proposed camera control scheme should take that into account.

Comment: @DMGregory There's nothing wrong with this DeviceMotionEvent object, in particular that the RotationRate is null.

Comment: Isn't there a sensor, that measures rotation?

Comment: I've attempted to clarify with an edit, as this question has 2 votes to close it as "unclear what you're asking", but I think it has potential. Does the result reflect your intention? Requests for further clarification: Have you tried processing the motion data event in some way already and gotten stuck? Do you know how to rotate the camera independently any motion data already?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the accelerometer, there's already a way to get the device's orientation with the `deviceorientation` event:

```
addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(e) {
    // This function is called when the phone rotates
    // e.alpha is the angle around the y axis (yaw)
    // e.beta is the angle around the x axis (pitch)
    // e.gamma is the angle around the z axis (roll)
});
```

If you really want to use the accelerometer, then here's how to do it:

Take the `acceleration` vector and subtract it from the `accelerationWithGravity` vector, the result is the gravity vector. This always points down (except if you are in space), so you can normalize the vector, get the angles of it and negate them. This should result in the orientatiom of the device.