# How to use Kalman's Filter to remove gyroscope drift of PS5 DualSense gamepad?

Tags: gamepad, accelerometer, gyroscope, sensor-fusion, playstation5

Playstation's gamepad allows us to use gyroscope and accelerometer data but it has a small drift which leads to mouse cursor vibration.

I think, we can combine gyroscope and accelerometer data into the Kalman's filter to remove that drift but I don't know how to properly use it.

Can you give me an example how to use gyro and accel data in Kalman's Filter to get correct gamepad orientation angles without drift?

Comment: [There's an implementation of a 6DOF Kalman filter](https://github.com/RTIMULib) linked from the [answer on sensor fusion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114518/39518) that I'd shared with you previously. Can you show us how you've tried implementing your Kalman filtering solution based on this example, and where you got stuck or need help?

Comment: @DMGregory that solution returns quaternion of device orientation. But I need filtered gyroscope and accelerometer values

Comment: You can compare two quaternions from subsequent frames to get a filtered measure of the rotation rate between them. You can use the quaternion to get the direction of gravity. If you want to compute non-gravitational acceleration, you can then subtract that value from the raw accelerometer reading to estimate device motion. Can you clarify what you want to do with these values that cannot be obtained via a quaternion as outlined above?

Comment: @DMGregory I have code that does a good job with calculation of gravity and calculation orientation quaternion. But result is a bit inaccurate if i put raw gyro and accelerometer values in it. So, I need to filter the raw gyro and accelerometer values first and then put to the processing code.

Comment: @DMGregory "You can use the quaternion to get the direction of gravity" - How?

Comment: Sensed acceleration due to gravity when at rest points up. Take your world up vector, run it through the inverse of your orientation quaternion, and you have the direction your accelerometer *should* be registering at 1 g if it's not accelerating. But it sounds like you're trying to double-dip on sensor fusion. If your current method does not behave well with real sensor data, I would recommend ditching it and switching to an algorithm like the one above, rather than daisy-chaining multiple different algorithms, increasing the complexity of your code and reducing the responsiveness.

Comment: Looks like, I need a quaternion based kalman filter which will take quaternion as input and return corrected quaternion.